# Determine the values of $a$ for which the system has $0,1,\infty$ solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

$$x + 2y = 1$$
$$2x + (a^2 - 5)y = a - 1$$
This was my attempt at solving for no solutions ($0x+0y\ne0$):
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1&2&1\\
0&-4(a^2-5)&a-3\end{array}\right]$$
$a^2-5=0\implies a=\sqrt5$, but the answer in the book is $a=-3$. How do I go about solving this problem??

Comment: In short, you set the wrong element of the last row to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you multiply the first equation by two and subtract it from the second equation, you get

$$ (a^2 - 9)y = a - 3 $$

and not

$$ -4(a^2 - 5)y = a - 3. $$

If $a = 3$, you get the equation $0 \cdot y = 0$ so $y$ can be arbitrary. If $a = -3$, you get the equation $0 \cdot y = -6$ which has no solutions. Finally, if $a \neq \pm 3$ then $y = \frac{a - 3}{a^2 - 9}$.

Answer (score 0):

It will have no solutions if the two equations are inconsistent.  That happens when $a=-3$

It will have infinitely many solutions when the two equations are redundant.  That happens when $a=3$.

Otherwise, the two equations are independent, and there's one solution.